# Increase Row Number when ever Product is encountered - T SQL - Single Query (More than one statement not allowed)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

There is a table like below one

```
ID  Vals
1   Product
2   Milk
3   Butter
4   Cheese
5   Yogurt
6   Product
7   Muesli
8   Porridge
9   Product
10  Banana
```

Output Needed like below

```
RWNUM   ID  Vals
1       1   Product
1       2   Milk
1       3   Butter
1       4   Cheese
1       5   Yogurt
2       6   Product
2       7   Muesli
2       8   Porridge
3       9   Product
3       10  Banana
```

Every time Product is encountered, the RWNUM column value will be increased by one.

This needs to be implemented in a single TSQL Query.

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a cumulative sum of "product":

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when val = 'Product' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as rwnum
from t;
```